# Chart will not display DataPoints

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I am trying to make a `Chart` using the values from a dictionary however my `Chart`doesn't display anything. My code runs fine with no errors and I have a chart on a form.

I have never made a chart in C# before so I have no clue what I am doing.

This is my code for filling it.

If I remove `StatChart.update()` it will display the total number of items in the `Dictionary` on the chart but that is all

```
    private void FillStatChart(Dictionary<string, int> dictionary)
    {
        int dicLength = dictionary.Count;
        StatChart.Series.Clear();
        StatChart.Series.Add("Occurences");
        foreach (System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint point in StatChart.Series["Occurences"].Points)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in dictionary)
            {
                for (int idx = 0; idx < dicLength; idx++)
                {
                    point.SetValueXY(idx, pair.Value);

                    StatChart.Update();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you updating existing points there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `Add` the new `DataPoints` to the `Points` collection.

Change this:

```
    foreach (System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint point in StatChart.Series["Occurences"].Points)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in dictionary)
        {
            for (int idx = 0; idx < dicLength; idx++)
            {
                point.SetValueXY(idx, pair.Value);

                StatChart.Update();
            }
        }
    }
```

to this:

```
    Series S = StatChart.Series["Occurences"];
    for (int idx = 0; idx < dicLength; idx++)
    {
        KeyValuePair<string, int> pair = dictionary.ElementAt(idx);
        S.Points.AddXY(idx, pair.Value);
        S.Points[idx].ToolTip = pair.Key;  // optional tooltip
    }
```

`SetValueXY` is only for **changing** the values of a `DataPoint` later.

Comment: Thanks that displays all the items as points, however they all have the same y value even though I know they are not all the same. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: Whoops, your triple loop has tripped me. I guess you only need one loop.. If you like you could add the key string in a tooltip...

Comment: Yep it works great now. But is there a way to display the key string under the x axis facing up towards the data?

Comment: That should be possible. Search for adding a 'custom label' !